# T-SQL search for returning customer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a question, where I'm struggeling with at the moment.
I really don't know how to solve this problem, it seems so simple.

I've got a Customer ID, and an Order Date.
I only want to show customer, that ordered things before 2015 AND buyed something lets say in the last 10 days.

I created a little test table for that - lets say it's January 2016:
[image]

Now there is Customer 1, that did a purchase on January and in year 2010. Ok that fits my need, I want to show him.
But customer 2 did a purchase on December last year, so he is a not a "returning" customer, but a customer that often buys my things. I dont want to show him.

I tryed something like this, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT [Kunden_ID],Bestellung
FROM [Immo].[dbo].[TEST] AS A
WHERE (Bestellung >=DATEADD (day,-10,getdate()) 
AND Bestellung <= DATEADD (month,-12,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two separate queries. The first finds those customers that bought something in the last 10 days. The second uses the **exists** query to find those same customers (join using ID) that bought more than 12 months ago.

Try this:

```
SELECT [Kunden_ID],Bestellung
FROM [Immo].[dbo].[TEST] AS A
WHERE (Bestellung >=DATEADD (day,-10,getdate())) 
and exists (
select 1
from [Immo].[dbo].[TEST] AS B
where a.[Kunden_ID] = b.[Kunden_ID]
AND b.Bestellung <= DATEADD (month,-12,getdate())
)
```

Another way to do this uses a Common Table Expression (CTE). It's a little easier to see the different queries.

```
With Get10Days as (
SELECT [Kunden_ID],Bestellung
FROM [Immo].[dbo].[TEST] AS A
WHERE (Bestellung >=DATEADD (day,-10,getdate())) 
)


select b.Kunden_ID
from [Immo].[dbo].[TEST] AS B
join Get10Days as A on a.Kunden_ID = b.Kunden_ID
where b.Bestellung <= DATEADD (month,-12,getdate())
```